# Can't run R script through Excel VBA on Macbook

Tags: r, excel, vba, macos

I am using a MacBook pro and recently saw a question answered here on running R scripts through VBA.  I tried running it with my own path and it is failing on the third line where it tries to create the shell object.  Is this a security "feature" on the Macbook or is something else to blame?

```
Sub RunRScript3()
Dim shell As Object
Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitTillComplete As Boolean: waitTillComplete = True
Dim style As Integer: style = 1
Dim errorCode As Integer
Dim path As String

path2 = "Users/kieroneil/Documents/Analytics Projects/test.R"
errorCode = shell.Run(path2, style, waitTillComplete)

End Sub
```

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 1):

There is a MacScript() function in mac VBA. The syntax looks like this:

```
MacScript("do shell script ""command""")
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't heard of MacScript() before.  It looks like it has been deprecated and replaced with AppleScriptTask().  Apparently I need VBA to call an AppleScript.  I'm still not sure if I can pass data into an R script and get the results back into Excel on a MacBook.

Comment: Sorry about that - I was not aware it is now deprecated. If by data you mean an argument, I think you should be able to do that. If you mean e.g. a data frame, I do not think you can do that.